# Why this property can't pass to this function?

Tags: ios, mobile, swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI by following the tutorial on apple developer site. And I meet this "passing error" in the *Building Lists and Navigation* section.

Before this section, the code look like this and it seems working well
[At the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VJ4Y.jpg)

But I follow the step that add a property to **MapView.swift** by coding this

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

Also in the **PreviewProvider** part to get the coordinate

```
MapView(coordinate: landmarkData[0].locationCoordinate)
```

The problem is that when I delete the hard-code part then the preview crushed.

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 29.554987, longitude: 115.984963)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIeMg.jpg)

So, what happened? Look forward the answer from you guys!

Comment: Would you provide your crashing code *as code*?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you share to us the whole project? There seems to be no problem with your code.